# How to change back to previous path quickly?

Tags: linux, path

This is a basic linux question I think, but I really want to know.

For example, currently I am in `/usr/bin`:

```
[x@localhost bin]$ pwd
/usr/bin
[x@localhost bin]$ cd /
[x@localhost /]$
```

Now I want to go back to previous path `/usr/bin`, how to do that quickly? I don't want to type `cd /usr/bin` again.

Answer (score 26):

The command `cd -` will allow you to quickly return to the last directory.

You may also be interested in the [`pushd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pushd) and [`popd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/popd) commands which allow even more control over your directory navigation.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the shell you use, there's usually a variable with the previous working directory.  In bash, I believe it's `$OLDPWD`