# How to stop bare bash cd (change directory command) from changing the working directory to $HOME?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I do this too often:

> ```
> $ pwd
> /a/long/long/way/from/anywhere
> $ cd # oops - meant to tab-complete something
> /home/$USER
> ```

Can `cd` defaulting to $HOME be disabled?

Comment: You can always switch back to the previous directory [using the `cd -` command](http://serverfault.com/questions/384930/how-to-change-back-to-previous-path-quickly).

Answer (score 2):

Two options I can think of:

- you can write an `alias` to default `cd` without arguments to whatever you want. This is in the line of using utilities like `cdargs` or `apparix`. Personally, I have been using [this](http://geocities.com/h2428/petar/acd_func.sh) `cd` replacement for quite a long time.
- patch `bash` to behave differently (`bash-4.2/builtins/cd.def`). Not sure if changing this default breaks other things, though.

```
228   if (list == 0)
229     {
230       /* `cd' without arguments is equivalent to `cd $HOME' */
231       dirname = get_string_value ("HOME");
232
233       if (dirname == 0)
234   {
235     builtin_error (_("HOME not set"));
236     return (EXECUTION_FAILURE);
237   }
238       lflag = 0;
239     }
```

Comment: Plenty of options - thanks! I've taken the suggestion to use `alias` and added a specific example as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, if you accidentally change to the wrong directory, you can go back to the previous directory with:

```
cd $OLDPWD
```

Answer (score 0):

This alias seems to do it:

> alias cd='HOME= cd'

I don't *think* it has any dangerous side effects...